# Ability to populate sum in scope of fields

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following format of data:

```
Machine | Description Time | Description | Total Time | SUM of Time
M1        20                 Desc1         123          1368   
M1        15                 Desc2         123          1368
M1        43                 Desc3         123          1368        
M2        42                 Desc2         456          1368
M2        10                 Desc1         456          1368
M2        124                Desc3         456          1368
M3        324                Desc4         789          1368
M3        429                Desc1         789          1368
M3        129                Desc2         789          1368
```

Machine, Description Time and Description are the RAW values.
Machine and "descriptions" related column are in separated tables.
Every machine has it's own Total Time: 123 for M1, 456 for M2 and 789 for M3.

The problem with the aggregation.

I've already populated "SUM of Time" using the following DAX, but I have it only in scope of all data:

```
CALCULATE(SUM('KPI'[Total Time]),ALLSELECTED(Descriptions))
```

How I can calculate "Total Time" in scope of every machine and exclude Description and Description Time...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a SUM based on [ALLEXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allexcept-function-dax), this will sum up the values for the selected columns.

```
CALCULATE(SUM('KPI'[Total Time]), ALLEXECPT('KPI', 'KPI'[Machine]))
```

This should give you, for example, M1 a value of 369